# How to find degree of freedom in SEM-CFA model? [Inquiring Clarification]

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, degrees-of-freedom, confirmatory-factor

I found a link that explains it.

http://reifman-sem.blogspot.com/2007/04/some-of-students-wanted-review-of.html

It is

$$Degree \;of\;Freedom (DF) = Total \;Elements - Total \;Free \;Parameters$$
*[correct me if I'm wrong]*

**Here is a model under my project:**

A latent model;
3 Latent Variables, 3 Indicators for each of two Latent Variables and the last Latent Variable with 4 indicators.

Hence, Total of 3 Latent and 10 Measured Variables.

**Nature of Variable Relationships**

Two latent variables are correlated with each other, while the same last latent variable is negatively correlated both of the other two.

All indicator / measured variables are expected to positively estimate unto their respective latent variables

By my own calculations

**Free Parameters :**

3 = Covariance of all latent variables

3 = Variance of all latent variables

10 = Covariances between latent and Manifest / Indicator Variables

10 = Residual Indicator variance

3 = Construct Variance

7 = freely estimated factor loadings (one loading per factor being fixed at 1)

[ Out of 3 manifest variables, there are 2 factor loadings not fixed each for 2 latent variables

Out of 4 manifest variables there are 3 factor loadings not fixed for the last latent variable ]

Now for **Total Elements**

Using the advised formula (from the link above):

$$\frac{(I^2) + I}{2}$$

where $$I = Manifest \;Variables$$

$$\frac{(10^2) + 10}{2} = 55$$

Hence,

\begin{align}
Degree \;of\;Freedom (DF) & = 55 - (3 + 3 + 10 + 10 + 3 + 3 + 7)\\ &= (55-36)\\ &= 19
\end{align}

Was my identifications of the elements and free parameters correct?
Was my calculation correct?

I'll be needing this for further calculation to determine sample size for validation project.

Comment: Can this be of some help? https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/279360/3277

Comment: Hi. @ttnphns. Unfortunately, the information is quite above my current level of my understanding. Guess I have to hope more replies coming in soon. 

But I appreciate you reaching out to provide some help.
Cheers.

Comment: Get to read some book on FA (which include chapters on CFA). They explain it.